# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

part1: why i have this error
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in
can anyone help me with this ?
when i run this query i get that error

```
 $checkuser = $c->query("select * from user where(email = 'test@test.com' or mobile = '0933' or username = 'test') limit 1") or die("$c->error");
```

$c is function to do this=

```
function db(){
$dbname = 'ro****';
$dbuser = 'roy*****2_fb';
$dbpass = '#******s';
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die('Cant connect to Database Server');
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");
return $mysqli;
}

$c = db();
```

part2:
and guys there is anyway to get $header in code below:

```
<?php
$header = 1;
?>
<div id="content">
</div>
<script>$.ajax({url:mypage.php,success:function(loaddataa){
$('#content').html(loaddataa);</script>
```

and in mypage.php

```
<? echo $header ?>
```

but its not get $header when its loaded with ajax
i actully try to load page without header and footer and do query just 1 time in header but i cant get in pages loaded with ajax
its have anyway?

Comment: i dont see what checkuser and header have todo which the error?

Comment: `what is this error?` would depend on the line of code that gives the error, which - I suspect - is not one of those added to the question.

Comment: How is $c assigned? Please show code.

Comment: i edited question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply `PDO`:

```
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$pdo = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $connection = new PDO($pdo, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function getFruit($connection) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}

getFruit($connection);
```

---

File `client.php`:

```
<?php
    // Array
    $header = array(
        'test' => 'PHP',
        'happy' => 'test'
    );

    // Encode
    $header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));
?>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mypage.php",
        data: { header: "<?=$header?>" }
    }).done(function(source) {
        $('#content').html(source);
    });       
</script>
```

And `mypage.php`:

```
<?php
    // Get
    $header = $_POST['header'];

    // Decode
    $header = json_decode(base64_decode($header));

    // Array
    var_dump($header);
?>
```

Comment: actully i dont want just $header i want querys in header page load in all page loaded with ajax

Comment: OK. Now it's for arrays...

Comment: sounds like its not have any standard way work like include - anway thank you . can you answer part 1 of my question?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistace. Now it's works. Wait I do part 1.